# How to apply Mobile First platform appcenter fix pack

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-appcenter

I download the Mobile First Platform fix pack(6.3.0.0), It contain the 6.3.0.0-MFPF-Pattern-IF201503120508.zip, when it unzip this, I found it's for app-center and analytic console fix pack, but I am not able to find the repository.config or diskTrag.inf file to add InstallManager's repository.

Could anybody can tell me how to install this fixpack.

Thanks
Kumaresan

Answer (score 1):

6.3.0.0-MFPF-Pattern-IF201503120508.zip is the Virtual application pattern installer. Here is the link to [install MobielFirst Platform Application Pattern Type](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/pureapp/t_pureapp_installing_mobile_application_platform_pattern_type.html)

But unless you are using the MobileFirst Platform Application Pattern Type, you do not need this.
To install the MobileFirst Platform Studio latest ifix, you need the 6.3.0.0-MFPF-StudioP2-IF201503120508.zip and the instructions are available [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.upgrade.doc/devenv/t_upgrade_studio.html?lang=en).

To install the MobileFirst Platform Server latest ifix, you need the 6.3.0.0-MFPF-Server-IF201503120508.zip and the instructions are available [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27028172).

If you want to install the fixpack in a production environment, please see instructions [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.upgrade.doc/devenv/c_roll_upgrd_apply_fix_pack_wl.html?lang=en).

Comment: Thanks TyLy, yes your rite. I am not using the application pattern type.